# Issue serving Ember app using nginx

Tags: ember.js, nginx

My nginx config below is returning a 404 for nested pages e.g. /blog after some changes to serve static pages to crawlers.The issue is being caused by this line:

```
if ($request_uri ~* "([^/]*$)")
```

It seems that this if test is in fact rewriting the request_uri - but how can i fix that?

**Full Config**

```
server {
    root /home/user/code/app-client/dist;
    index index.html index.htm;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    access_log  /home/user/code/app-server/log/nginx_access.log;
    error_log   /home/user/code/app-server/log/nginx_error.log info;

    location / {  
         set $snapshot 0;

# Extract all text after last / from url
    if ($request_uri ~* "([^/]*$)") {
  set $last_path_component $1;
}

if ($last_path_component = "") {
  set $last_path_component "home";
}

    # Google crawler
    if ($args ~* "(^|.*&)_escaped_fragment_=.*") {
        set $snapshot 1;
    }

    # Social sharing bots
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "Facebot|FacebookExternalHit|LinkedInBot|TwitterBot|Baiduspider") {
        set $snapshot 2;
    }

# Google crawler for pages other than homepage
    if ($arg__escaped_fragment_) {
       set $snapshot 3;
    }

# Google crawl for nested pages e.g. article/the-title
    if ($arg__escaped_fragment_ ~* "(/)") {
       set $snapshot 2;
    }

    #excluded suffixes (assumed static). Broken into two conditionals for readability
    if ($uri ~ "\.(jpe?g|png|svg|gif|ico|tiff?|css|less|js|doc|zip|rar|exe|iso|dmg)") {
        set $snapshot 0;
    }
    if ($uri ~ "\.(dat|ppt|psd|pdf|xls|mp3|mp4|m4a|wav|avi|mpe?g|swf|flv|mkv|torrent)") {
        set $snapshot 0;
    }

    #prevent loops
    if ($http_x_ajs_calltype) {
        set $snapshot 0;
    } 

# Google crawl for the homepage
if ($snapshot = 1) {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ /snapshot-proxyhome.html last;
    }

# Social media crawlers and crawler nested urls
if ($snapshot = 2) {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ /snapshot-proxy$last_path_component.html last;
}

# Google crawl for pages (non-nested)  other than homepage
    if ($snapshot = 3) {
   rewrite ^(.*)$ /snapshot-proxy$arg__escaped_fragment_.html last;
    }

try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
    location /static {
        root /home/user/code/app-server/;
    }
    location /assets {
        root /home/user/code/app-client/dist/; # do nothing and let nginx handle this as usual
    }
}

#redirect  to https
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.app.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally solved it using a map. Some notes:

- IfIsEvil in location - numerous people pointed this out but I could not find an alternative to accomplish what I want - If anyone does, please comment or answer. Additionally, the IfisEvil doc says if is not inconsistent so if properly tested in your setup, it can be used.
- Google crawling (_escaped_fragment_) - numerous people pointed out that it is no longer necessary if you dont use # urls, but this does not seem to be the case. Per this [Google doc](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174992#) , you still need to tell Google to crawl your site even if you dont use #urls - you do this by including a header tag in index.html. I read in several places that Google does execute JS these days, but this was not the case for our site. Even if Google does start to execute JS for all sites, none of the major social bots currently do, so you do need to be able to serve static pages to them, otherwise you wont be indexed by them and sharing from your site will not look pretty.
- The pre-rendered/static pages for our site are served from a cloudfront instance I set up for this purpose (snapshotproxy). There are various services out there that will do all of this for you, but they cost money and have some limitations for social sharing e.g. for a blog page to be properly shared on fb/twitter with image, title and extract, you need to move the necessary info into the title and description tags of your head - automated snapshots from those services do not do that)

_

```
map $request_uri $last_path_component {
       ~*(?P<last>[^/]*$) $last;
}

server {
        #your setup here
}

location / {
        set $snapshot 0;

        if ($last_path_component = "") {
           set $last_path_component "home";
        }

        # Google crawler
        if ($args ~* "(^|.*&)_escaped_fragment_=.*") {
            set $snapshot 1;
        }

        # Social sharing bots
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "Facebot|FacebookExternalHit|LinkedInBot|TwitterBot|Baiduspider") {
            set $snapshot 2;
        }

        # Google crawler for pages other than homepage
        if ($arg__escaped_fragment_) {
           set $snapshot 3;
        }

        # Google crawl for nested pages e.g. article/the-title
        if ($arg__escaped_fragment_ ~* "(/)") {
           set $snapshot 2;
        }

        #excluded suffixes (assumed static). Broken into two conditionals for readability
        if ($uri ~ "\.(jpe?g|png|svg|gif|ico|tiff?|css|less|js|doc|zip|rar|exe|iso|dmg)") {
            set $snapshot 0;
        }
        if ($uri ~ "\.(dat|ppt|psd|pdf|xls|mp3|mp4|m4a|wav|avi|mpe?g|swf|flv|mkv|torrent)") {
            set $snapshot 0;
        }

        #prevent loops
        if ($http_x_ajs_calltype) {
            set $snapshot 0;
        } 

       # Google crawl for the homepage
       if ($snapshot = 1) {
           rewrite ^(.*)$ /snapshot-proxyhome.html last;
       }

       # Social media crawlers and crawler nested urls
       if ($snapshot = 2) {
           rewrite ^(.*)$ /snapshot-proxy$last_path_component.html last;
       }

       # Google crawl for pages (non-nested)  other than homepage
        if ($snapshot = 3) {
          rewrite ^(.*)$ /snapshot-proxy$arg__escaped_fragment_.html last;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

Comment: You might also want to keep an eye on [ember-cli-fastboot](https://github.com/tildeio/ember-cli-fastboot) - one large reason for fast boot I believe is SEO.. some additional info about fast boot (a little old): [tomdale.net](http://tomdale.net/2015/02/youre-missing-the-point-of-server-side-rendered-javascript-apps/) [emberjs.com](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/12/22/inside-fastboot-the-road-to-server-side-rendering.html)

Answer (score 2):

`try_files $uri /index.html;`

That should work for you.. It should try get the file from disk and if it doesn't find it it will then get `index.html`.. I'm not sure why you have `?/$request_uri` in your config but removing it should fix your issue.

Comment: @jmurphayau Unfortunately this does not work. It does not serve subpaths like /blog

Comment: It works for me.. Can you update your question with Nginx version and your full config?

Comment: Some progress - if I remove everything from the location block except `try_files $uri /index.html` , it all works. But in this case i dont understand why the other lines are causing the issue - we need them for seo

Comment: Wow - theres a lot of stuff in there.. Try turning on [rewrite_log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite_log) which will print the rewrite results to the error_log - that might help you debug..

Comment: Where is your `/snapshot-proxy` location? What is `/snapshot-proxy` doing/accessing?

Comment: Hi, I have figured out what is causing the issue (see update to question), but not yet how to fix it

Comment: Why do you think it is rewriting the request_uri? According to http://regexr.com/3b8ad the regex may be an error - an 'infinite' match? Not sure what that means.. Try changing it to `([^/]+$)`

Comment: First I isolated it by removing elements from the config and putting back 1 by 1 until the error occurred again. Googling then confirmed that nginx does rewrite it in an if

Comment: `if` looks like something bad - they advise to use it at the `server` level (not the `location` level like you're doing) IF you have to use it - but they advise against using it unless you understand it.. after reading http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil I would stay away from `if`... Very unexpected behaviour

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81055/discussion-between-jmurphyau-and-run-loop).